# group by data in left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables: orders and product_orders
there are one id in orders table. i.e: 9
and order_id(as foreign key) in product_orders repeated 3 times. So I want this three entry in product_orders table with one entry in orders table. 
My query is:

```
SELECT orders.*,order_products.* FROM orders LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.id=order_products.order_id
```

this gives :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

My expected result is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [orders] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9
                        [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                        [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                        [mobile] => 01673050495
                        [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                        [city_id] => 2
                        [location_id] => 5
                        [status] => No contact
                        [chashed] => NO
                        [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                        [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                        [comment] => 
                    )

                [order_products] => Array
                    (
                          [0] => Array(
                                   [id] => 2
                                   [order_id] => 9
                                   [product_id] => 1
                                   [pieces] => 1
                                )
                           [1] => Array(
                                   [id] => 3
                                   [order_id] => 9
                                   [product_id] => 2
                                   [pieces] => 1
                                )   
                             [2] => Array(
                                  [id] => 4
                                  [order_id] => 9
                                  [product_id] => 3
                                  [pieces] => 1
                                ) 

                    )

            )
    )

    I used GROUP BY orders.id. But no luck.
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? and which programming language to get the result of your query?

Comment: mysql database and I am using php language

Comment: You can use `array_column()` to aggregate them. See my answer here on your related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093087/formatting-an-array-using-php/31094106#31094106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically expecting a result that is not possible to obtain with a SQL query: you want a *hierarchical* structure, with a single `order` and a set of `order_product` for that `order`, while the query returns a *flat* table, with one row for each `order` together with the information of a different `order_product`. This is the way in which SQL works.

A way to solve your problem is to do a sort of post-processing in php, after getting all the rows, group all of them that have the same `order` part, and produce a new array for the `order_product` part related to that order.

Comment: An important point here:  this is not functionality that *MySQL* supports.  Most databases support for hierarchical and recursive queries.