# formatting an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which have duplicate data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-24 16:17:45
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [img] => 1.jpg
                    [desc] => description
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 00:28:26
                    [bppp] => 44000
                    [sppp] => 45000
                    [discount] => 25
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 1
                    [location_id] => 1
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [modified] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [order_id] => 10
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-24 16:17:45
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [img] => 1.jpg
                    [desc] => description
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 00:28:26
                    [bppp] => 44000
                    [sppp] => 45000
                    [discount] => 25
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => Resonance of creativity with C++
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:32:52
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [img] => 2.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:33:41
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 20
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 1
                    [location_id] => 1
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [modified] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [order_id] => 10
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => Resonance of creativity with C++
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:32:52
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [img] => 2.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:33:41
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 20
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => programming by story C
                    [writer] => Hasibul Hasan Shanto
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:35:57
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [img] => 3.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:36:26
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 10
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 1
                    [location_id] => 1
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [modified] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [order_id] => 10
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => programming by story C
                    [writer] => Hasibul Hasan Shanto
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:35:57
                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [img] => 3.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:36:26
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 10
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

)
```

I want to format this array and produce the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 2
                    [location_id] => 5
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [order_id] => 9
                            [product_id] => 1
                            [pieces] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [order_id] => 9
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [pieces] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [order_id] => 9
                            [product_id] => 3
                            [pieces] => 1
                        )

                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং
                            [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                            [created] => 2015-06-24 16:17:45
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => Resonance of creativity with C++
                            [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:32:52
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => programming by story C
                            [writer] => Hasibul Hasan Shanto
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:35:57
                        )

                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 1
                            [img] => 1.jpg
                            [desc] => description
                            [created] => 2015-06-28 00:28:26
                            [bppp] => 44000
                            [sppp] => 45000
                            [discount] => 25
                            [service_charge] => 30
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [img] => 2.jpg
                            [desc] => 
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:33:41
                            [bppp] => 150
                            [sppp] => 250
                            [discount] => 20
                            [service_charge] => 30
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 3
                            [img] => 3.jpg
                            [desc] => 
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:36:26
                            [bppp] => 150
                            [sppp] => 250
                            [discount] => 10
                            [service_charge] => 30
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 01673050495
                    [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
                    [city_id] => 1
                    [location_id] => 1
                    [status] => No contact
                    [chashed] => NO
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [modified] => 2015-06-28 03:30:25
                    [comment] => 
                )

            [order_products] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Array
                        ( [id] => 6
                           [order_id] => 10
                           [product_id] => 1
                           [pieces] => 1
                       )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [order_id] => 10
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [pieces] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [order_id] => 10
                            [product_id] => 3
                            [pieces] => 1
                        )

                )

            [products] => Array
                (
                   [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং
                            [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                            [created] => 2015-06-24 16:17:45
                   )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => Resonance of creativity with C++
                            [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:32:52
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [name] => programming by story C
                            [writer] => Hasibul Hasan Shanto
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:35:57
                        )

                )

            [psettings] => Array
                (
                  [0] => Array
                        (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [img] => 1.jpg
                    [desc] => description
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 00:28:26
                    [bppp] => 44000
                    [sppp] => 45000
                    [discount] => 25
                    [service_charge] => 30
                    )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [img] => 2.jpg
                            [desc] => 
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:33:41
                            [bppp] => 150
                            [sppp] => 250
                            [discount] => 20
                            [service_charge] => 30
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 3
                            [img] => 3.jpg
                            [desc] => 
                            [created] => 2015-06-26 07:36:26
                            [bppp] => 150
                            [sppp] => 250
                            [discount] => 10
                            [service_charge] => 30
                        )

                )

        )


)
```

How can I do this. I reformat simple array but this does not make sense to me to format. It makes me cry. Please help me. If any helper function is suggested it will be really a gift. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like below:-

```
<?php
$firstArray = Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            'orders' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 9,
                    'name' => 'Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan',
                    'email' => 'sattar.kuet@gmail.com',
                    'mobile' => '01673050495',
                    'alt_mobile' => '01818953250',
                    'city_id' => 2,
                    'location_id' => 5,
                    'status' => 'No contact',
                    'chashed' => 'NO',
                    'created' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'modified' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'comment' => ''
                ),
            'order_products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 2,
                    'order_id' => 9,
                    'product_id' => 1,
                    'pieces' => 1
                ),
            'products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 1,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং',
                    'writer' => 'Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan',
                    'created' => '2015-06-24 16:17:45'
                ),
            'psettings' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 1,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'product_id' => 1,
                    'img' => '1.jpg',
                    'desc' => 'description',
                    'created' => '2015-06-28 00:28:26',
                    'bppp' => 44000,
                    'sppp' => 45000,
                    'discount' => 25,
                    'service_charge' => 30
                ),
        ),
    '1' => Array
        (
            'orders' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 9,
                    'name' => 'Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan',
                    'email' => 'sattar.kuet@gmail.com',
                    'mobile' => '01673050495',
                    'alt_mobile' => '01818953250',
                    'city_id' => 2,
                    'location_id' => 5,
                    'status' => 'No contact',
                    'chashed' => 'NO',
                    'created' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'modified' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'comment' => ''
                ),
            'order_products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 3,
                    'order_id' => 9,
                    'product_id' => 2,
                    'pieces' => 1
                ),
            'products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 2,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Resonance of creativity with C++',
                    'writer' => 'Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan',
                    'created' => '2015-06-26 07:32:52'
                ),
            'psettings' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 2,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'product_id' => 2,
                    'img' => '2.jpg',
                    'desc' => '',
                    'created' => '2015-06-26 07:33:41',
                    'bppp' => 150,
                    'sppp' => 250,
                    'discount' => 20,
                    'service_charge' => 30
                ),
        ),
    '2' => Array
        (
            'orders' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 9,
                    'name' => 'Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan',
                    'email' => 'sattar.kuet@gmail.com',
                    'mobile' => '01673050495',
                    'alt_mobile' => '01818953250',
                    'city_id' => 2,
                    'location_id' => 5,
                    'status' => 'No contact',
                    'chashed' => 'NO',
                    'created' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'modified' => '2015-06-27 12:49:34',
                    'comment' => ''
                ),
            'order_products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 4,
                    'order_id' => 9,
                    'product_id' => 3,
                    'pieces' => 1
                ),
            'products' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 3,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'programming by story C',
                    'writer' => 'Hasibul Hasan Shanto',
                    'created' => '2015-06-26 07:35:57'
                ),
            'psettings' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 3,
                    'category_id' => 1,
                    'product_id' => 3,
                    'img' => '3.jpg',
                    'desc' => '',
                    'created' => '2015-06-26 07:36:26',
                    'bppp' => 150,
                    'sppp' => 250,
                    'discount' => 10,
                    'service_charge' => 30
                ),
        ),
);
$new_array = array();

foreach($firstArray as $key=> $arr){
    if($key == 0){
        $new_array[0]['orders'] = $arr['orders'];
        $new_array[0]['order_products'][] = $arr['order_products'];
        $new_array[0]['products'][] = $arr['products'];
        $new_array[0]['psettings'][] = $arr['psettings'];
    }else{
         foreach($new_array as $key=> $newarr){
              if($arr['orders'] == $newarr['orders']){
                $new_array[$key]['order_products'][] = $arr['order_products'];
                $new_array[$key]['products'][] = $arr['products'];
                $new_array[$key]['psettings'][] = $arr['psettings'];
              }else{
                  $new_array[] = $arr;
              }
         }
    }

}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Output:-   https://eval.in/388565.

Note:- don't worry about the array i putted. I just take your array and formatted it for running purpose and checking at my end. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @anant kumar singh. it works fine for one element but not for more than one.

Comment: What do you  mean to say that. i didn't get you.

Comment: I edit my question. please test your code for my updated array

Comment: Its not our work that you update your array and ask for solution again and again. i gave you a code. at-least do some efforts and modification and get your solution yourself. Sorry for my wordings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple job for `array_column()` ([manual reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)). Like this (`$array` is your source):

```
$composite = [];
$composite['orders'] = array_column($array, 'orders')[0];
$composite['order_products'] = array_column($array, 'order_products');
$composite['products'] = array_column($array, 'products');
$composite['psettings'] = array_column($array, 'psettings');

print_r($composite);
```

This results in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [orders] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
            [email] => sattar.kuet@gmail.com
            [mobile] => 01673050495
            [alt_mobile] => 01818953250
            [city_id] => 2
            [location_id] => 5
            [status] => No contact
            [chashed] => NO
            [created] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
            [modified] => 2015-06-27 12:49:34
            [comment] => 
        )

    [order_products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [order_id] => 9
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [pieces] => 1
                )

        )

    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => নভোযানের নাম সি প্রোগ্রামিং
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-24 16:17:45
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => Resonance of creativity with C++
                    [writer] => Engr. Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:32:52
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => programming by story C
                    [writer] => Hasibul Hasan Shanto
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:35:57
                )

        )

    [psettings] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [img] => 1.jpg
                    [desc] => description
                    [created] => 2015-06-28 00:28:26
                    [bppp] => 44000
                    [sppp] => 45000
                    [discount] => 25
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [img] => 2.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:33:41
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 20
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [img] => 3.jpg
                    [desc] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-26 07:36:26
                    [bppp] => 150
                    [sppp] => 250
                    [discount] => 10
                    [service_charge] => 30
                )

        )

)
```

If you need to aggregate multiple such arrays into one master array that contains it all, then you can for example wrap it inside a simple loop and add a numeric index for each composite set:

```
$composite = [];

foreach($arrays as $num=>$array) {
    $composite[$num]['orders'] = array_column... // etc.
}
```

Also make note of the `index_key` feature of `array_column` mentioned in the manual, may come in handy if you want to use the order IDs as the main keys --- though for that, you'd have to re-factor the loop logic a bit. Let me know if it's a relevant concern and I'll add more; or if this is enough as-is.